# select and insert in one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
   SELECT 
       RowNumber, PercentMatch, @constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal
   FROM 
       dbo.MatchDate(@Date)
```

dbo.MatchDate(@date) is an inline TVF which looks like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MatchDate] (@DateFromUser nvarchar(20))
    RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    SELECT 
        p.Rowid AS RowNumber , 
        CAST(100 AS INT) AS PercentMatch 
    FROM 
        dbo.Patients p
    WHERE 
        datename(day, p.DOB) = @DateFromUser

GO
```

I have this query where I am selecting and inserting in one query. Now I have an extended requirement which needs me to check `ModifiedAt` for rows returned by `dbo.MatchDate(@Date)`and insert in `#Temp2` only if `ModifiedAt` for rows returned is greater than some time  T.

How can I do this in above query ?

Comment: can you tell us all the columns returned by `dbo.MatchDate(@Date)`, i.e. is ModifiedAt returned?

Comment: Yep what wrong with the query? it should work as long as the data types match in the select and in #Temp2 table.

Comment: @GB: dbo.MatchDate(@Date) returns only RowId and PercentMatch of the rows returned. However, I can customize it to return ModifiedAt of the columns if that is needed.

Comment: @M.Ali: Never said anything is wrong with the query.

Comment: @GB: But I would not need to insert the ModifiedAt value in #Temp2 table. How I may proceed ?

Comment: @Simran just because the function returns additional columns doesn't mean you have to change your INSERT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could Add Modified date to your function BUT ONLY if it is appropriate to do so, don't add it if you are only doing it for convenience.

If you choose that route then your query should just be

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
   SELECT 
       RowNumber, PercentMatch, @constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal
   FROM 
       dbo.MatchDate(@Date)
   WHERE 
       ModifiedAt > @YourComparisonDateTime
```

However, you wont necessarily need to add ModifiedAt because you can still perform joins on a table valued function.

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
   SELECT 
       f.RowNumber, f.PercentMatch, @constVal, f.PercentMatch * @constVal
   FROM 
       dbo.MatchDate(@Date) f
       inner join YourSourceTable t
          on f.RowNumber = t.RowNumber --t.RowNumber being the identity or PK column that matches f.RowNumber
          -- and any other required join conditions
   WHERE
       t.ModifiedAt > @YourComparisonDateTime
```

I have made a lot of assumptions here so you will need to fill in the blanks or provide additional information.

Hope that helps you out.

**EDIT**

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
SELECT 
    f.RowNumber, f.PercentMatch, @constVal, f.PercentMatch * @constVal
FROM 
    dbo.MatchDate(@Date) f
    inner join Patients p
        on f.RowNumber = p.RowID
    inner join ResultsStored rs
        on rs.RowID = f.RowNumber
WHERE
    p.ModifiedAt > rs.ModifiedAt
```

Comment: That helped. But I have a small query : I get the value T (against which the ModifiedAt is compared) from a table called ResultsStored which can be joined on RowId column only. How I may integrate that here ?

Comment: Give me the name of the table we will get ModifiedAt from as well as the join column(s), and I will write another query that includes the join for Modified At and another join to get the comparison time. Give me the name of the column for the comparison time too please.

Comment: dbo.MatchDate is returning rows from dbo. Patients table which has a ModifiedAt column that needs to be compared against ModifiedAt column of ResultsStored table. All these tables can be joined on RowId column.

Comment: See how you get on with that one, let me know if it isn't quite right.

Comment: That's right :) Thanks a ton for keeping up with me.

Comment: I just realized that it results in duplication of rows in #Temp2 table  because of a join on ResultsStored table. May be we need to use some kind of subquery and not a join ?

Comment: I think I have answered a related question of yours... is this "I want to get records from the patients table that have been modified since the ResultsStored table was last updated", and Patients has one record but results stored has many records - one for each "version"?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I just needed to check it with EXISTS instead of direct jons

Comment: Cool, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a where clause in select statement (provided you table valued function returns a column named ModifiedAt)

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
   SELECT 
       RowNumber, PercentMatch, @constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal
   FROM 
       dbo.MatchDate(@Date) where ModifiedAt > @T
```